# Cocoa Touch - Countdown Timer

Tags: cocoa, countdown

How would one go about creating a 15 second countdown timer..I've seen NSTimer but was wondering if their was an easier way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. You could do thread blocking with performSelector:withObject:afterDelay, but that will freeze your app in place unless you make a new thread, which is harder than just using NSTimer.

Welcome to embedded development.